# Python - Flatting Dictionary where some keys are 'missing'

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  I am checking a nested dictionary for a specific key and assigning that to a variable.    I will be using it to make a mysql insert shortly.

**My main issue is that if the key is not present (which sometimes happens) I dont want the code to fail, I just want to sent the variable to empty.**

This code seems to work but I have to do something similar to about 20 differnt key values so I would like to make sure I am doing it the best way

```
if 'Model' in  ItemAttributes:
    Model=ItemAttributes['Model']['value']
else:
    Model=''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### dict.get

Here is one solution:

```
Model = ItemAttributes.get('Model', {}).get('value', '')
```

If the "Model" key does not exist in the `ItemAttributes` dictionary, you return an empty dictionary, on which you use `dict.get('value', '')`. This will, of course, return an empty string if the "Model" key does not exist.

#### if / else

An alternative solution is to add an extra function call and have this function test for whether the key exists. Here we use a ternary statement. This is effectively what you are doing now, but wrapping the logic in a function for easy repeated access:

```
def get_value(d, key1, key2):
    return d[key1][key2] if key1 in d else ''

Model = get_value(ItemAttributes, 'Model', 'value')
```

#### catch KeyError

A more generic solution is to use `try` / `except` and catch `KeyError`. If any key is missing, the function will return an empty string. Otherwise, `reduce` + `getitem` will cycle through the nested dictionary to access the appropriate value given a list of keys.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):
    try:
        return reduce(getitem, mapList, dataDict)
    except KeyError:
        return ''

Model = getFromDict(ItemAttributes, ['Model', 'Value'])
```

Comment: This is really nice as it makes it read a bit cleaner.  To populate some of the variables I will be iterating 2 levels of dictionary deep.   Others 3 and others 4..  So I would have to figure out how to modify this to accept variable number of arguments which may be beyond my skill but worth a shot

Comment: @personalt, There's a better solution, wait one moment :)

Comment: @personalt, See the last solution. It'll work with any arbitrary list of keys representing the "path" you wish to take.

Answer (score 2):

```
model = ItemAttributes.get('Model', {}).get('value', '')
```

Not sure if it's much better, but it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using get is often the best solution.
Another solution is to catch `KeyError`exception:

```
try: 
    Model=ItemAttributes['Model']['value']
except KeyError:
    Model=''
```

Model will be set to `''` if `'Model'` is not in `ItemAttributes` or if `'value'` is not in `ItemAttributes['Model']`